# If the circumcenter of the triangle $ABC$ is on the incircle of the triangle,then prove that $\cos A+\cos B+\cos C=\sqrt2$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

If the circumcenter of the triangle $ABC$ is on the incircle of the triangle,then prove that $\cos A+\cos B+\cos C=\sqrt2$

How should i attempt this question?I thought over it hard but could not crack through.Some hints will help me.Please guide me.

Comment: consider the triangle in a coordinate system

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner,what should be right way to choose coordinates,besides taking one vertex as (0,0),to simplify the calculations.

Comment: i would choose $$A(0,0),B(c,0),C(b\sin(\alpha),b\cos(\alpha))$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Euler's theorem in geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_in_geometry),

$$r^2=R(R-2r)\iff r^2+2Rr-R^2=0$$

$$\implies r=\dfrac{-2R\pm\sqrt{4R^2+4R^2}}2=R(\sqrt2-1)$$ as $R,r>0$

Now using [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumradius.html), $$\dfrac rR=\cos A+\cos B+\cos C-1$$

Answer (score 2):

Let me try.

Let $d$ be a distance between the circumcentre and incentre.

From [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem_in_geometry), you have $$d^2= R(R-2r).$$

When the circumcentre is on the incircle, we have $d=r$. Then, $$r^2 = R^2 - 2Rr.$$

So, you get $$\left(\frac{r}{R}\right)^2 + 2\frac{r}{R} - 1 = 0.$$

Then, you get $$\frac{r}{R} = -1 + \sqrt{2}$$ (Do you see why not $-1-\sqrt{2}$?).

Recall that we have $$rR = \frac{abc}{2(a+b+c)}$$ (For example, see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle))

Note that $a = 2R\sin A$, $b = 2R\sin B$ and $c = 2R\sin C$. We have

$$\frac{r}{R} = 2 \frac{\sin A\sin B\sin C}{\sin A + \sin B + \sin C}.$$

We have $$\sin A + \sin B +\sin C = 4\cos \frac{A}{2}\cos \frac{B}{2}\cos \frac{C}{2}.$$

Now, we have $$\frac{r}{R} = 4\sin \frac{A}{2}\sin \frac{B}{2}\sin \frac{C}{2}.$$

Note that $$\cos A + \cos B +\cos C = 4\sin \frac{A}{2}\sin \frac{B}{2}\sin \frac{C}{2} + 1.$$

So, we have $$-1+\sqrt{2} = 4 \sin \frac{A}{2}\sin \frac{B}{2}\sin \frac{C}{2}.$$

Thus, we get $$\cos A +\cos B + \cos C = \sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: i did not knew which theorems you can use, but you must also prove the given formulas